# Stacking numpy array with offset

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to locate some values into an `np.array` with `searchsorted` and I would like to get the resulting array stacked with itself modulo an offset.

I can do this with:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1, 3.5), (1, 2.1), (1, 5.8), (1, 0.)])    
b = np.arange(0.5, 5.5, 1.)

c = np.searchsorted(b, a[:, 1])
d = np.column_stack((c, c + 1))
```

but I'd like to do it more directly, something similar to:

```
c = np.column_stack((np.searchsorted(b, a[:, 1]), np.searchsorted(b, a[:, 1]) + 1))
```

without repeating the call to `np.searchsorted`.

For the example above, the result should be:

```
[[3 4]
 [2 3]
 [5 6]
 [0 1]]
```

Any idea?

Comment: By "more directly" do you just mean one line? The first method you propose looks pretty clear and understandable to me, and I'm not sure you're going to be able to improve in terms of efficiency either.

Comment: `np.searchsorted(b, a[:, 1])[:,None] + [0,1]`?

Comment: I have another operation to do do after this and I was trying to vectorize the calculation because the b array can be quite long (1e4).

Comment: @Divakar that's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!